# Method for returning highest value in a list using iterator (Java)

Tags: java, iterator, compareto

I'm working on a card class in Java and i'm unsure on the implementation of a certain method. I need to include a static method (which i'll call max) that uses a compareTo method to find and return the highest value card in a list of cards. However, I need to use an Iterator to traverse the list.

Below is the compareTo method i've implemented. It sorts the cards into descending order, first by suit then rank.

```
public int compareTo(Card card) {

if (this.rank.compareTo(card.rank) > 0){
    return 1;
} else if (this.rank.compareTo(card.rank) < 0){
    return -1;
} else {

    if(this.suit.compareTo(card.suit) > 0){
        return 1;
    } else if (this.suit.compareTo(card.suit) < 0){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I'm also including my two enums for suit and rank.

```
enum Rank{TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), 
          NINE(9), TEN(10), JACK(10), QUEEN(10), KING(10), ACE(11);

          private int value;

          Rank(int i){
              value=i;
          }

          public int getValue(){
              return value;
          }

          public Rank getPrevious(){
              return values()[ordinal() > 0 ? ordinal()  - 1 : 0];
          } 

}   


enum Suit{CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES;

          public static Suit randomSuit(){
              Random random = new Random();
              return values()[random.nextInt(values().length)];

          }            
}
```

I don't want to include the whole class so things don't get confusing but it includes variables, rank and suit of type Rank and Suit with a single constructor. Accessor methods for rank and suit and a toString() method.

I made a rough method following the answer.

```
Iterator<E> it = collection.iterator;
E max = null;
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if(max == null) {
        max = it.next();
    } else {
        e = it.next();
        if(e.compareTo(max) > 0) {
            max = e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We at least need to see what your `max()` method looks like.

Comment: Apologies, I realise I didn't make it very clear. The max() method is the issue, I don't have a method yet as i'm unsure how to implement it. I assume it will use the compareTo method to sort a list and then return the largest (which would be the first) value but the iterator part has thrown me. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you need just the maximum value, you don't need to actually sort the list. Instead:

- Validate that the list has at least one element, i.e. `it.hasNext() == true`
- Store the first value (`it.next()`) in a variable
- Iterate through the rest of the list in a while loop, and whenever the item you're at is higher than the one in your variable, store the new max in the variable
- At the end, the variable will hold the maximum value

Comment: I've added a method. Was that what you were suggesting? Can it be refined or does it need editing?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. I suggest you test it to see if it does what you want. But apart of a minor syntax error and a missing local variable declaration, it should work.

Comment: As for refining, the only thing I'd change is I'd call `it.next()` only once, before the condition right at the start of the `while` body - so that it is obvious it's called in every iteration and therefore there's no infinite loop possible. That's just matter of readability though, not a functional error.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply and apologies for my late reply. I was wondering what you meant when you said 'minor syntax error'. And the missing declaration is of e right?

Comment: I think I meant missing `()` after `collection.iterator`.